# error al usar mysqli->query()

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un archivo conexión y un archivo modelo estoy intentando hacer  un `MVC` con `POO`. Tengo conexión a ala base de datos pero me sale un error al utilizar el método query de `mysqli`.

El error me lo marca en esta linea:

> **$resultado = $this->conexion->query($consulta);** Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in
>   C:\laragon\www\proyecto\model\clientes.php:14 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\laragon\www\proyecto\model\clientes.php(28): clientes->listar() #1
>   {main} thrown in C:\laragon\www\proyecto\model\clientes.php on line 14

Archivo conexión:

```
    <?php
class accesoDB
{
    function conexionbd(){
        $servidor = 'localhost';
        $usuario = 'root';
        $contraseña = '';
        $db = 'clientes';
        $conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$contraseña,$db)or die("Problemas con el servidor de BD. ");
        $conexion->set_charset('utf8');
        //echo 'correcto';
        return $conexion;
    }   
}
/*$validar = new accesoDB();
$validar->conexionbd();*/
?>
```

Archivo modelo

```
        <?php
    class clientes{

        protected $conexion;

        public function _construct(){
            $this->conexion = accesoDB::conexionbd();
        }

        public function listar(){
            $datos= array();
            $consulta = "SELECT `idCliente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `activo` FROM tblclientes ORDER BY nombre";
            echo $consulta;
            $resultado = $this->conexion->query($consulta);
            printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", $resultado->num_rows);
            //Retorna una matriz fetch_assoc()
            while ($filaTmp = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
                $datos [] = $filaTmp;
                if($resultado){
                    return $datos;
                }else{
                    return 'no se encontraron datos';
                }
            }
        }
    }
$varCliente = new clientes();
$varCliente->listar();
    ?>
```

Comment: En el constructor de tu clase hija veo que tratas de leer un método como si fuera estático pero si revisas la clase padre no lo es pues no dice static

Comment: ya lo intente como dices pero no cambio en nada public static function conexionbd(){

Comment: apenas lo esta viendo fui a comer jaja lo borraste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu funcion `construct` de la clase `cliente` solo tiene un subguion `_`, deberian ser 2:

```
        public function __construct(){
            $this->conexion = accesoDB::conexionbd();
        }
```

---

y la funcion `conexionbd` de la clase `accesoDB` deberia ser static

```
    public static function conexionbd(){
        $servidor = 'localhost';
        $usuario = 'root';
        $contraseña = '';
        $db = 'clientes';
        $conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$contraseña,$db)or die("Problemas con el servidor de BD. ");
        $conexion->set_charset('utf8');
        //echo 'correcto';
        return $conexion;
    }
```

Comment: Exacto ........

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Pero no debería ser `public` sino `private`, por que al declarar `public` permites que cualquiera pueda ver esa información

Answer (score 0):

Propongo que hagas lo siguientes cambios en tu código

Primero a la clase que contiene la conexión, su método vuelvelo estático

```
<?php
class accesoDB
{
    public static $conexion;
    static function conexionbd(){
        $servidor = 'localhost';
        $usuario = 'root';
        $contraseña = '';
        $db = 'clientes';
        self::$conexion = new mysqli($servidor,$usuario,$contraseña,$db)or die("Problemas con el servidor de BD. ");
        $conexion->set_charset('utf8');
        //echo 'correcto';
        return self::$conexion;
    }   
}
```

Luego en tu clase hija, la invocas de este modo:

```
class clientes extends accesoBD{

    public function listar(){
        $datos= array();
        $consulta = "SELECT `idCliente`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `activo` FROM tblclientes ORDER BY nombre";
        echo $consulta;
        $resultado = parent::$conexion->query($consulta);
        printf("La selección devolvió %d filas.\n", $resultado->num_rows);
        //Retorna una matriz fetch_assoc()
        while ($filaTmp = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            $datos [] = $filaTmp;
            if($resultado){
                return $datos;
            }else{
                return 'no se encontraron datos';
            }
        }
    }
}
$varCliente = new clientes();
$varCliente->listar();
?>
```

Es decir

- Vuelve estática la propiedad conexión
- Vuelve estático al método de la conexión
- Lo anterior hará que no requieras hacer una instancia
- Haz que la clase hija extienda de la principal
- Invoca ens clase hija a conexión como parent
- Remueve el método constructor de la clase hija